# set lc_time_names in PHP script is not responding

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to change the `time names` of the `date` column in my (mysql) database.

When I run the following statement in phpMyAdmin I get the correct response

```
set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL'; SELECT id, name, date_format(date1, '%e %M %Y') AS date1, date_format(date2, '%e %M %Y') AS date2 FROM `users`
```

When I try to run this statement in my PHP script I get no response. Here is that part of my PHP script:

```
$sql = "set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL'; SELECT id, name, date_format(date1, '%e %M %Y') AS date1, date_format(date2, '%e %M %Y') AS date2 FROM `users` ";
$sqlTot .= $sql;
$sqlRec .= $sql;
//concatenate search sql if value exist
if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

    $sqlTot .= $where;
    $sqlRec .= $where;
}
```

Does someone know what is wrong and how I can fix it?

When I run the statement without `set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL';` the PHP script is responding.

**Edit 1:**

```
$sql = "set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL'; ";
$sql .= "SELECT id, name, date_format(date1, '%e %M %Y') AS date1, date_format(date2, '%e %M %Y') AS date2 FROM `users` ";
$sqlTot .= $sql;
$sqlRec .= $sql;
//concatenate search sql if value exist
if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

    $sqlTot .= $where;
    $sqlRec .= $where;
}


$sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";

$queryTot = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sqlTot) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));


$totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($queryTot);

$queryRecords = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch employees data");

//iterate on results row and create new index array of data
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) { 
    $data[] = $row;
}   

$json_data = array(
        "draw"            => intval( $params['draw'] ),   
        "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
        "data"            => $data   // total data array
        );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
```

Comment: assuming that you are using mysqli , use mysqli_multi_query instead of plain query if you want to execute multiple queries in one statement.

please refer: http://php.net/manual/kr/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Comment: Yes I am using mysqli. I already tried to add `$sql .= "set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL';` But it was no success.

Comment: Do I need to change `mysqli_query`?

Comment: use mysqli_multi_query()

Comment: It is still the same. See `Edit 1` in my first post.

Comment: hmm.. did you try to execute "set lc_time_names='nl_NL'" query only in php script and check if there's still no response ( no select )?

Comment: The data is sended to a table on another page `<table id="employee_grid1"`. I call the PHP code with a javascript function `$('#employee_grid1').DataTable({`. When I try to execute `set lc_time_names='nl_NL` without select the table will stay also empty

Comment: Still not fixed

Comment: is it responding when query set lc_time_names only?

Of course result empty, for you skipped select statement. If set lc_time_names single query works ok, then split your statement.

Comment: It is the same. With `not responding` I mean no result. When I run the statement  `set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL';` I get no result. When I run it with the SELECT, I also get no result

Comment: Then, there's something another problem. I guess query string you build may not correct? did you check  the query strings ($sqlRec, $sqlTot) are correct? If not, print (error_log or something) those strings right before execute query to see the queries are same as what you wanted.

Comment: `($sqlRec, $sqlTot)` are working without the second statement `set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL';`. Can adding of the statement affect the working of `($sqlRec, $sqlTot)`?

Comment: Theoretically, it's not. I can't figure out what the problem is... sorry.
One suggestion. If your queries works without setting lc_time_names, then
try setlocale() php function instead.

setlocale(LC_ALL,'nl_NL');

Comment: I tried `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');`. But it had no affect on the date in the table

Comment: Someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string is like:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
```

I fixed the problem by adding a query after the connection string:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
$conn->query("SET lc_time_names = 'nl_NL'");
```